# The Kraus representation of a completely depolarising channel

Tags: quantum-information

I have an answer, but I want to know how to get from the left hand size to the right hand side:
$$
    \frac{1}{d^2} \sum_{i=1}^{d^2} U_i \rho U_i^{\dagger}
  = \operatorname{Tr}[\rho] \frac{I}{d}.
$$
Here the $U_i$ are $d*d$ orthogonal unitary operators.
[(Original image here.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZS555.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2827506/173147) already provides a full proof passing through Choi's representation.

Here I'll give an alternative, direct proof.

The set of matrices $\{U_i\}_{i=1}^{d^2}$ is, by definition, complete.
This means that any matrix $\rho$ can be decomposed with it as (the $d$ normalization factor here follows from the normalization choice $\newcommand{\Tr}{\operatorname{Tr}}\Tr(U_i^\dagger U_j)=d \delta_{ij}$):

$$\rho = \frac{1}{d}\sum_{i=1}^{d^2} \Tr(U_i^\dagger \rho )U_i.\tag A$$
In particular, such decomposition applied to the "component matrices" (1) $|j\rangle\langle k|$ gives:

$$
|j\rangle\langle k|=\frac{1}{d} \sum_{i=1}^{d^2}(u^*_i)_{jk} U_i.
$$

But of course, because $\langle m|j\rangle\langle k| n\rangle=\delta_{mj}\delta_{kn}$, the above immediately gives
$$
\delta_{mj}\delta_{kn} =
\frac{1}{d}\sum_{i=1}^{d^2} (u_i^*)_{jk} (u_i)_{mn}. \tag B
$$

Strong of (B), we may now see that

$$
\frac{1}{d^2}\sum_{i=1}^{d^2} U_i\rho U_i^\dagger =
\frac{1}{d^2}\sum_{i=1}^{d^2} \sum_{jklm} (u_i)_{jk} \rho_{kl} (u^*_i)_{ml} |j\rangle\!\langle m| =
\frac{1}{d} \Tr(\rho) I.
$$

---

### Appendix 1

Interestingly, (B) can also be seen as arising directly from the completeness of the operators $\newcommand{\bU}{\boldsymbol{U}}U_i$.
To see this, let us denote with $\tilde{\bU}_i$ the vectorization of $U_i$, so that if $U_i=\sum_{jk}(u_i)_{jk} |j\rangle\langle k|$, then
$\tilde{\bU}_i\equiv\sum_{jk}(u_i)_{jk}|j\rangle|k\rangle$.
Is is then easy to see that the orthogonality/orthonormality of the operators $U_i$ in the Hilbert-Schmidt inner product is equivalent to the orthogonality/orthonormality of the vectors $\tilde{\bU}_i$ in the regular Euclidean inner product:

$$\Tr(U_i^\dagger U_j)=\langle \tilde{\bU}_i, \tilde{\bU}_j\rangle.$$
The completeness of the $U_i$ is then stated as the completeness relation for the $\tilde{\bU}_i$:
$$\sum_i \tilde{\bU}_i\tilde{\bU}_i^* = I,\tag C$$
where $\tilde{\bU}_i^*$ is the dual of $\tilde{\bU}_i$.

As can be readily checked, (B) is nothing but (C) after expansion of the indices.

### Appendix 2: diagrammatic notation

This identity can also be directly shown via diagrammatic notation, if one is familiar with it.
Equation (C) above can be written as

[image]

which is equivalent to

[image]

Applying the above to a matrix $\rho$, it follows that

[image]

which is the result.

---

(1) I'm here using the convention, common in quantum mechanics, of writing basis vectors as $|j\rangle$ instead of $\boldsymbol{e_j}$, and their duals as $\langle j|$ instead of $\boldsymbol{e_j}^*$.

Comment: That is Dirac notation from quantumn physics.

Comment: Excellent, this would have been my approach as well.

Answer (score 3):

I'll use here the notation from [John Watrous' book](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~watrous/TQI/). Denote the standard orthonormal basis of the $d$-dimensional space as $e_1,\dots,e_d\in\mathbb{C}^d$, let $\operatorname{L}(\mathbb{C}^d)$ denote the set of $d\times d$ matrices (i.e. linear operators), and let $\operatorname{U}(\mathbb{C}^d)$ denote the set of $d\times d$ unitary matrices. The space $\operatorname{L}(\mathbb{C}^d)$ is itself a $d^2$-dimensional complex vector space with inner product given by 
$$
\langle X,Y\rangle = \operatorname{Tr}(X^*Y)
$$
for all $d\times d$ matrices $X$ and $Y$, where $^*$ denotes the conjugate transpose (i.e., $^\dagger$ in your notation). There is an isomorphism between the spaces of $d\times d$ matrices and vectors in $\mathbb{C}^d\otimes\mathbb{C}^d$ that is defined as 
$$
\operatorname{vec}(uv^*) = u\otimes v
$$
for all $u,v\in\mathbb{C}^d$, and extended linearly to all $d\times d$ matrices. It holds that 
$$
\langle \operatorname{vec}(X),\operatorname{vec}(Y)\rangle = \langle X,Y\rangle = \operatorname{Tr}(X^*Y)
$$
for all $d\times d$ matrices $X$ and $Y$. Finally, the Choi representation of a linear map $\Phi:\operatorname{L}(\mathbb{C}^d)\rightarrow\operatorname{L}(\mathbb{C}^d)$ is the operator $J(\Phi)\in\operatorname{L}(\mathbb{C}^d\otimes\mathbb{C}^d)$ defined as 
$$
J(\Phi)= \sum_{a,b=1}^d \Phi(e_ae_b^*)\otimes e_ae_b^*.
$$
Two such linear mappings are the same if and only if they have the same Choi representation.

Let $\Phi:\operatorname{L}(\mathbb{C}^d)\rightarrow\operatorname{L}(\mathbb{C}^d)$ be the linear map defined as
$$
\Phi(X)=\frac{\operatorname{Tr}(X)}{d} I.
$$
It is clear that $J(\Phi)=\frac{1}{d}I\otimes I$. This is the map on the right-hand side of the equation in your question.

Now let $\bigl\{U_{a,b}\,:\, a,b\in\{1,\dots,d\}\bigr\}\subset\mathrm{U}(\mathbb{C})$ be an arbitrary collection of orthogonal unitary matrices such that 
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(U_{a,b}^*U_{a',b'})=d\, \delta_{a,a'}\delta_{b,b'}.
$$
Define the operator $V\in\operatorname{L}(\mathbb{C}^d\otimes\mathbb{C}^d)$ as 
$$
V = \frac{1}{d}\sum_{a,b=1}^d e_a\otimes e_b \operatorname{vec}(U_{a,b})^*.
$$
It is evident that $V$ is unitary, since it may be checked that 
$$
VV^* = \sum_{a,b=1}^d e_ae_a^*\otimes e_be_b^* = I\otimes I.
$$
It therefore holds that $I\otimes I = V^*V = \frac{1}{d}\sum_{a,b=1}^d\operatorname{vec}(U_{a,b})\operatorname{vec}(U_{a,b})^*$

Define the linear mapping $\Psi:\operatorname{L}(\mathbb{C}^d)\rightarrow \operatorname{L}(\mathbb{C}^d)$ as $$\Psi(X)=\frac{1}{d^2}\sum_{i=1}^{d^2}U_j XU_j^*$$ for all matrices $X\in\operatorname{L}(\mathbb{C}^d)$.
The Choi representation of $\Psi$ is
\begin{align*}
J(\Psi)
&=\frac{1}{d^2}\sum_{a,b=1}^d \operatorname{vec}(U_{a,b})\operatorname{vec}(U_{a,b})^*\\
& = \frac{1}{d} V^*V\\
& = \frac{1}{d} I \otimes I \\
& = J(\Phi),
\end{align*}
and thus $\Phi=\Psi$.